# Specify that a file is Always CopyToOutputDirectory outside of the .csproj file

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, .net-core, gitignore

I have a file I want git to ignore locally (not in .gitignore but in .git/info/exclude), but I also need that file to be copied to bin on build.

Is there a way I can specify that either in a separate file that can also be ignored locally without needing to modify any files that I can't ignore local changes to?

Comment: You can specify the file to be added to OutputDirectory from VS file properties. and files in the BIN folder does not get tracked. right

Comment: Files in the bin folder do not get tracked, but which file are you referring to that stores the VS file properties? The .sln file and the .csproj file are tracked.

Comment: Any files that are part of the solution can be "CopiedToOutput" from VS> File > Properties

Comment: The file properties that you are describing are stored as XML nodes inside the existing .csproj file, which is tracked, so I can't modify it and only have local changes.